# Orthogonal path routing

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **TLDR;** Is there a way I can specify a start and end point it it would route (hopefully orthogonally) around all nodes and other paths.

I'm converting a large number of visio flow charts to `TikZ` and keep running into one issue. Orthogonal* paths with more than one bend are hard to do. I'm also trying to keep the diagrams dynamic so any future changes can be made without tweaking the chart a bunch.

Now, I'm able to make these and keep them dynamic, but it seems much harder than it should be. Take the red line: that line required a minimum of 3 distinct points and to keep it dynamic, I ended up using 5! It would be nice if I could just specify a start and end point it it would route around all nodes and other paths.

*I'm using terminology from Omnigraffle, so what I mean is that any change in direction for the path is multiple of 90 degrees.

[image: orthogonal paths2]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em ,
                        minimum width = 6em,
                        inner sep = 5pt
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{data}    = [ trapezium, 
                        draw, 
                        trapezium left angle=60, 
                        trapezium right angle=120pt,
                        minimum height = 6em, 
                        text width = 5em
                       ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix [column sep = 2.5em, row sep = 2em] (mtrx)
    {

    \node [state] (a) {a}; &[1em]
    \node (b) {}; \\

    \node [action] (c) {c}; &
    \node [action] (d) {d}; \\

    \node [test] (e) {e}; &
    \node [test] (f) {f}; \\

   \node [action] (g) {g}; &
    \node [action] (h) {h}; \\

    \node [action] (i) {i};&
    \node [action] (j) {j}; \\

    &
    \node [state] (k) {k}; \\
    };

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (a) -- (c);
    \path [line] (c) -- (e);

    \path [line] (e) -- node [right, near start] {Yes} (g);
    \path [line] (e.east) -- node [above] {No} ( $(e.east)!0.3!(f.west)$ ) |- ( $(g)!0.45!(i)$ );

    \path [line] (g) -- (i);

    \path [line,red] let \p1=( $(a.south)!0.6!(b.south)$ ) in (i.south) -- +(0, -0.5) -| (\p1) -| (d.north);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2L6N.png)

Comment: If you provide a code snippet for your example/what you archieved so far nobody had to guess what you were able to do on your own. Do you know, for instance, about the `|-`/`-|` syntax?

Comment: What is the context of *dynamic* here? Note that node avoidance etc. are non-trivial tasks and not possible with TikZ (yet). Also can you show us your 5 point code? I am almost sure that it can be reduced via relative positioning.

Comment: I'm meaning dynamic is the sense that I'm using relative positions so I could write a book in one of the nodes and the lines would adjust accordingly.

Comment: Here's the 5 point line pulled out of the code `\path [line,red] let \p1=( $(a.south)!0.6!(b.south)$ ) in (i.south) -- +(0, -0.5) -| (\p1) -| (d.north);`. The let is cruft from an older attempt and unnecessary.

Comment: Would `\draw[-triangle 45,red] (i.south) -- ++(0,-5mm) -| ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]d.north west) -| (d);` be simple enough?

Comment: That's not bad... Not what I had hoped for, but it may be enough for now. I am however intrigued by the "(yet)". Is there active development on node avoidance etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you often need this functionality, I recommend this to create a specific command, eg

```
\newcommand{\renvoi}[3][pos=0.5]{
\path (#2) -- (#3)coordinate[#1](mm);
\draw[-latex,green] (#2) --($(#2.south)+(0,-0.5)$)-| (mm) |- ($(#3.north)+(0,0.5)$)--(#3);
}
```

You'll be able to use almost all returns as in the example below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}


\newcommand{\renvoi}[3][pos=0.5]{
\path (#2) -- (#3)coordinate[#1](mm);
\draw[-latex,red] (#2) --($(#2.south)+(0,-0.5)$)-| (mm) |- ($(#3.north)+(0,0.5)$)--(#3);
}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em ,
                        minimum width = 6em,
                        inner sep = 5pt
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{data}    = [ trapezium, 
                        draw, 
                        trapezium left angle=60, 
                        trapezium right angle=120pt,
                        minimum height = 6em, 
                        text width = 5em
                       ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix [column sep = 2.5em, row sep = 2em] (mtrx)
    {

    \node [state] (a) {a}; &[1em]
    \node (b) {}; \\

    \node [action] (c) {c}; &
    \node [action] (d) {d}; \\

    \node [test] (e) {e}; &
    \node [test] (f) {f}; \\

   \node [action] (g) {g}; &
    \node [action] (h) {h}; \\

    \node [action] (i) {i};&
    \node [action] (j) {j}; \\

    &
    \node [state] (k) {k}; \\
    };

    % Draw edges


\renvoi{i}{j}
\renvoi{e}{g}
\renvoi[left=3em of g]{e}{i}
\renvoi[pos=0.7]{f}{c}
\renvoi[right=3em of f]{f}{d}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

indicating the option selected by you or pass your link

- in the middle of the two nodes    `\renvoi{i}{j}`  default
- `\renvoi\[pos=0.7\]{f}{c}`  the crossing point is 0.7 on the segment (f) (c)
- `\renvoi[right=3em of f]{f}{d}` the crossing point is to the right of 3em  (positioning the library is required to use this option)

it has yet to improve this command to draw the link in all cases even add text or change the style of the link.

[image]

Comment: This seems like the best answer I'm going to get until TikZ adds node avoidance for paths.

Pretty slick command btw.