# How to draw orthogonal line with arrow avoiding collision to the existing rectangles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried the following it almost works, but looks ugly:

1. The line is broken when it turns.
2. It's not really perfectly horizontal and vertical, just my
   approximation.

The lines between USB and Comp are not horizontal.

How can I make it prettier? I tried to learn from the example of this one, but I lack a good foundation of tikz to adapt to mine: [Orthogonal path routing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71031/orthogonal-path-routing)

Here is how it looks:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{computer/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt}}
\tikzset{UHD_int/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 7em, line width=1pt}}
\tikzset{switch_int/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 7em, line width=1pt}}
\tikzset{display/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 8em, line width=1pt}}
\tikzset{touchPanel/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt}}
\tikzset{mouseKeyboard/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt}}

\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[computer] (first) {Comp. 1};
  \node[computer,below=of first] (second) {Comp. 2};
  \node[computer,below=of second] (third) {Comp. 3};
  \node[computer,below=of third] (fourth) {Comp. 4};
  \node[computer,below=of fourth] (fifth) {Comp. 5};
  \node[computer,below=of fifth] (sixth) {Comp. 6};
  \node[computer,below=of sixth] (seventh) {Comp. 7};

  \node[UHD_int, right=5cm of first] (first_video_in) {HDMI 1};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of first_video_in] (second_video_in) {HDMI 2};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of second_video_in] (third_video_in) {HDMI 3};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of third_video_in] (fourth_video_in) {HDMI 4};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of fourth_video_in] (fifth_video_in) {DisplayPort 5};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of fifth_video_in] (sixth_video_in) {DisplayPort 6};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of sixth_video_in] (seventh_video_in) {RGB/VGA 7};

  \node[UHD_int, below=of seventh_video_in] (LAN) {LAN};
  \node[touchPanel, below=1.5cm of LAN] (touchPanel) {Touch Panel Controller};
  \node[UHD_int, above=of first_video_in] (HDMI_out) {HDMI out};

  \node (UHD) [above=0.6cm of first_video_in] {UHD};
  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(UHD) (HDMI_out) (first_video_in) (second_video_in)
      (third_video_in) (fourth_video_in) (fifth_video_in) (sixth_video_in) (seventh_video_in) (LAN)}] {};

  \node[display, right=2cm of HDMI_out] (display) {big screen};
  \draw[->] (HDMI_out) -- (display);

  \node[switch_int, left=5cm of first] (first_usb) {USB 1};
  \node[switch_int,below=of first_usb] (second_usb) {USB 2};
  \node[switch_int,below=of second_usb] (third_usb) {USB 3};
  \node[switch_int,below=of third_usb] (fourth_usb) {USB 4};
  \node[switch_int,below=of fourth_usb] (fifth_usb) {USB 5};
  \node[switch_int,below=of fifth_usb] (sixth_usb) {USB 6};
  \node[switch_int,below=of sixth_usb] (seventh_usb) {USB 7};

  \node[switch_int, below=of seventh_usb] (USB_mouse/keyboard) {USB 2.0};
  \node[mouseKeyboard, below=1.5cm of USB_mouse/keyboard] (mouseKeyboard) {Operator mouse \& keyboard};
  \node[switch_int, above=of first_usb] (touch_panel_control) {RS-232};

  \node (Switch) [above=0.6cm of first_usb] {Switch};
  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(Switch) (touch_panel_control) (first_usb) (second_usb)
      (third_usb) (fourth_usb) (fifth_usb) (sixth_usb) (seventh_usb) (USB_mouse/keyboard)}] {};

  \draw[->] (first) -- (first_video_in);
  \draw[->] (first_usb) -- (first);
  \draw[->] (second) -- (second_video_in);
  \draw[->] (second_usb) -- (second);
  \draw[->] (third) -- (third_video_in);
  \draw[->] (third_usb) -- (third);
  \draw[->] (fourth) -- (fourth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (fourth_usb) -- (fourth);
  \draw[->] (fifth) -- (fifth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (fifth_usb) -- (fifth);
  \draw[->] (sixth) -- (sixth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (sixth_usb) -- (sixth);
  \draw[->] (seventh) -- (seventh_video_in);
  \draw[->] (seventh_usb) -- (seventh);

  \draw[->] (mouseKeyboard) -- (USB_mouse/keyboard);
  \draw[->] (touchPanel) -- (LAN);

  \node[label] at (-3.5,0.3)  {muse/keyboard in};
  \node[label] at (3.1,0.3)  {video out};
\node [below left=1.7cm of mouseKeyboard] (belowMouseKeyboard) {};
\node [left=2.25cm of touch_panel_control] (leftRS232) {};
\node [below= of touchPanel] (belowTouchPanel) {};
\path [line] (touchPanel.south) -- (belowTouchPanel) -- (belowMouseKeyboard) -- (leftRS232) -- (touch_panel_control);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is depreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a modified version of your code, no great changes included.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{computer/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}
\tikzset{UHD_int/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 7em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}
\tikzset{switch_int/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 7em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}
\tikzset{display/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 8em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}
\tikzset{touchPanel/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}
\tikzset{mouseKeyboard/.style={shape=rectangle, draw, node distance=-1pt, minimum width = 5em, line width=1pt,minimum height=.7cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[computer] (first) {Comp. 1};
  \node[computer,below=of first] (second) {Comp. 2};
  \node[computer,below=of second] (third) {Comp. 3};
  \node[computer,below=of third] (fourth) {Comp. 4};
  \node[computer,below=of fourth] (fifth) {Comp. 5};
  \node[computer,below=of fifth] (sixth) {Comp. 6};
  \node[computer,below=of sixth] (seventh) {Comp. 7};

  \node[UHD_int, right=5cm of first] (first_video_in) {HDMI 1};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of first_video_in] (second_video_in) {HDMI 2};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of second_video_in] (third_video_in) {HDMI 3};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of third_video_in] (fourth_video_in) {HDMI 4};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of fourth_video_in] (fifth_video_in) {DisplayPort 5};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of fifth_video_in] (sixth_video_in) {DisplayPort 6};
  \node[UHD_int,below=of sixth_video_in] (seventh_video_in) {RGB/VGA 7};

  \node[UHD_int, below=of seventh_video_in] (LAN) {LAN};
  \node[touchPanel, below=1.5cm of LAN] (touchPanel) {Touch Panel Controller};
  \node[UHD_int, above=of first_video_in] (HDMI_out) {HDMI out};

  \node (UHD) [above=0pt of HDMI_out] {UHD};
  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(UHD) (HDMI_out) (first_video_in) (second_video_in)
      (third_video_in) (fourth_video_in) (fifth_video_in) (sixth_video_in) (seventh_video_in) (LAN)}] {};

  \node[display, right=2cm of HDMI_out] (display) {big screen};
  \draw[->] (HDMI_out) -- (display);

  \node[switch_int, left=5cm of first] (first_usb) {USB 1};
  \node[switch_int,below=of first_usb] (second_usb) {USB 2};
  \node[switch_int,below=of second_usb] (third_usb) {USB 3};
  \node[switch_int,below=of third_usb] (fourth_usb) {USB 4};
  \node[switch_int,below=of fourth_usb] (fifth_usb) {USB 5};
  \node[switch_int,below=of fifth_usb] (sixth_usb) {USB 6};
  \node[switch_int,below=of sixth_usb] (seventh_usb) {USB 7};

  \node[switch_int, below=of seventh_usb] (USB_mouse/keyboard) {USB 2.0};
  \node[mouseKeyboard, below=1.5cm of USB_mouse/keyboard] (mouseKeyboard) {Operator mouse \& keyboard};
  \node[switch_int, above=of first_usb] (touch_panel_control) {RS-232};

  \node (Switch) [above=0pt of touch_panel_control] {Switch};
  \node [draw=black!50, fit={(Switch) (touch_panel_control) (first_usb) (second_usb)
      (third_usb) (fourth_usb) (fifth_usb) (sixth_usb) (seventh_usb) (USB_mouse/keyboard)}] {};

  \draw[->] (first) -- (first_video_in);
  \draw[->] (first_usb) -- (first);
  \draw[->] (second) -- (second_video_in);
  \draw[->] (second_usb) -- (second);
  \draw[->] (third) -- (third_video_in);
  \draw[->] (third_usb) -- (third);
  \draw[->] (fourth) -- (fourth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (fourth_usb) -- (fourth);
  \draw[->] (fifth) -- (fifth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (fifth_usb) -- (fifth);
  \draw[->] (sixth) -- (sixth_video_in);
  \draw[->] (sixth_usb) -- (sixth);
  \draw[->] (seventh) -- (seventh_video_in);
  \draw[->] (seventh_usb) -- (seventh);

  \draw[->] (mouseKeyboard) -- (USB_mouse/keyboard);
  \draw[->] (touchPanel) -- (LAN);

  \node[label] at (-3.5,0.3)  {muse/keyboard in};
  \node[label] at (3.1,0.3)  {video out};
\node [below left=1.7cm of mouseKeyboard] (belowMouseKeyboard) {};
\node [left=2.25cm of touch_panel_control] (leftRS232) {};
\node [below= of touchPanel] (belowTouchPanel) {};
%\path [line] (touchPanel.south) -- (belowTouchPanel) -- (belowMouseKeyboard) -- (leftRS232) -- (touch_panel_control);

\draw[-triangle 45,very thick] 
    (touchPanel.south) |- ([yshift=-1.5cm]mouseKeyboard.south)
        -| ([xshift=-1cm]mouseKeyboard.west)
        |- (touch_panel_control);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I have done:

- Set `minimum height` for every nodes. The inconsistent heights cause the two columns to be mis-aligned.
- Remove the broken line and substitute it with a path which has some `|-` and `-|`.